# Is there a magic function with can extract all select keys/nested keys including array from jsonb

Tags: postgresql

Given a jsonb and set of keys how can I get a new jsonb with required keys.

I've tried extracting key-values and assigned to text[] and then using jsonb_object(text[]). It works well, but the problem comes when a key has a array of jsons.

```
create table my_jsonb_table 
(
data_col jsonb
);

insert into my_jsonb_table (data_col) Values ('{
    "schemaVersion": "1",
    "Id": "20180601550002",
    "Domains": [
        {
            "UID": "29aa2923",
            "quantity": 1,
            "item": "book",
            "DepartmentDomain": {
                "type": "paper",
                "departId": "10"
            },
            "PriceDomain": {
                "Price": 79.00,
                "taxA": 6.500,
                "discount": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "UID": "bbaa2923",
            "quantity": 2,
            "item": "pencil",
            "DepartmentDomain": {
                "type": "wood",
                "departId": "11"
            },
            "PriceDomain": {
                "Price": 7.00,
                "taxA": 1.5175,
                "discount": 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "finalPrice": {
        "totalTax": 13.50,
        "total": 85.0
    },
    "MetaData": {
        "shopId": "1405596346",
        "locId": "95014",
        "countryId": "USA",
        "regId": "255",
        "Date": "20180601"
    }
}
')
```

This is what I am trying to achieve :

```
SELECT some_magic_fun(data_col,'Id,Domains.UID,Domains.DepartmentDomain.departId,finalPrice.total')::jsonb FROM my_jsonb_table;
```

I am trying to create that magic function which extracts the given keys in a jsonb format, as of now I am able to extract scalar items and put them in text[] and use jsonb_object. but don't know how can I extract all elements of array

expected output :

```
 {
    "Id": "20180601550002",
    "Domains": [
        {
            "UID": "29aa2923",
            "DepartmentDomain": {
             "departId": "10"
            }
        },
        {
            "UID": "bbaa2923",
            "DepartmentDomain": {
                "departId": "11"
            }
        }
    ],
    "finalPrice": {
        "total": 85.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Relational data such as this is not a good use for a JSON column. Instead, I'd recommend building a traditional relational structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any magic. You have to rebuild it yourself.

```
select jsonb_build_object(
    -- Straight forward
    'Id', data_col->'Id',
    'Domains', (
        -- Aggregate all the "rows" back together into an array.
        select jsonb_agg(
            -- Turn each array element into a new object
            jsonb_build_object(
                'UID', domain->'UID',
                'DepartmentDomain', jsonb_build_object(
                    'departId', domain#>'{DepartmentDomain,departId}'
                )
            )
        )
        -- Turn each element of the Domains array into a row
        from jsonb_array_elements( data_col->'Domains' ) d(domain)
    ),
    -- Also pretty straightforward
    'finalPrice', jsonb_build_object(
        'total', data_col#>'{finalPrice,total}'
    )
) from my_jsonb_table;
```

This probably is not a good use of a JSON column. Your data is relational and would better fit traditional relational tables.